# How do you permanently write to a text file in Python?

Tags: python

I am able to write to a text file using .write(). But after I close() the file and open it again all the written data is gone...? Is there any way that I can permanently save this data on the file?

```
def writeToFile():
    myFile = open("myText.txt","w")
    for each in range(8,10):
        record = "This is record number {} in the file\n".format(each)
        myFile.write(record)
    myFile.close()

writeToFile()
```

So what i meant was that the first time i run this program it appends to the file. After this when i close the program and run it again i want it to write to the file again, but instead it only overrides it, i.e the earlier data is deleted each time i close the program.

Comment: Are you opening the file again using another call to `open(filename, 'w')` or just viewing it in a text editor?

Comment: You'll have to show us some code. This doesn't look like a standard behaviour

Comment: show your code!

Comment: Try `file.flush` before you `close` it.

Comment: I have edited the post... @WoodyPride

Comment: I have edited the post^ @EricDuminil

Comment: `myFile = open("myText.txt","w")` change to `myFile = open("myText.txt","a")` ?..

Comment: It works... thanks! @VaoTsun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you wanted to write was indeed permanently written... until you opened again overwriting the previous data.

You have different modes to open the file.

If you know that the file has important data and only want to read it, use this mode.

```
file = open('./path_to_file', 'r')
```

If you want to overwrite the data, use this one instead:

```
file = open('./path_to_file', 'w')
```

Optionally, you can use this other way instead, and it will close the file for you.

```
with open('./path_to_file', 'r') as read_file:
    for line in read_file:
        print line
```

This will open the file, read it line by line writing it on the screen and closing it for you at the end.

Finally, if you need to open it again and append new content at the end of the file, just use this:

```
file = open('./path_to_file', 'a')
```

Comment: I only need to write to the file. Every time close the program and run it again the earlier data is overwritten. I have explained above in the post(edited).

Comment: Then just changing 'w' modifier and start using 'a' would solve your problem.

Comment: @AkilRiaz You are welcome. I've edited the answer so maybe you can accept it and help others when they end up reading your question.